# How do I flip the gameobject at every Dotween loop?

Tags: unity-game-engine, dotween

```
transform
    .DOPath(path, animDuration, pathType, pathMode, 10).SetLoops(-1, LoopType.Yoyo)
    .SetEase(ease);
```

This is my simple dotween code to follow path. After every yoyo I want my object to flip or change direction towards its next path waypoint. Is there any dotween way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DoTween has `OnStepComplete()`.

DOTween:

> Sets a callback that will be fired each time the tween completes a single loop cycle (meaning that, if you set your loops to 3, OnStepComplete will be called 3 times, contrary to OnComplete which will be called only once at the very end). *[More...](http://dotween.demigiant.com/documentation.php)*

```
void Start()
{
    transform
        .DOPath(path, animDuration, pathType, pathMode, 10)
        .SetLoops(-1, LoopType.Yoyo)
        .SetEase(ease).OnStepComplete(FlipScpite);
}

private void FlipScpite()
{
    _spriteRenderer.flipX = !_spriteRenderer.flipX;
}
```